# Is $y^2=x(x-1)^2$ an immersed submanifold?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is the curve $y^2=x(x-1)^2$ an immersed submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

[image]

It's certainly not embedded since it intersects itself at $(1,0)$. I'm aware of techniques to prove a subset is not a immersed submanifold, but how can you find an appropriate topology and smooth structure to show this is immersed? It seems hard to pick one out of the blue.

Comment: Very loose hint: can you find a parametrization of the curve?  That will provide you with a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to your curve, and showing that that's an immersion should be straightforward.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I could only find $t\mapsto (t,\sqrt{t(t-1)^2})$ when $t\geq 0$ and $t\mapsto (-t,-\sqrt{-t(-t-1)^2})$ when $t\leq 0$, but that traces out the curve differently. It's injective away from $0$ and $1$ but those are still problems.

Comment: It would be helpful to state what definition of "immersed submanifold" you're using. If it is "the image of a smooth immersion," then most of the answers here settle the question. But I have a feeling that might not be the definition you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your curve is the image $\gamma (\mathbb R)$ of the global immersion $$  \gamma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2:t\mapsto (t^2,t^3-t)$$

**Edit**
The idea for the parametrization comes from algebraic geometry:
Consider the one parameter family of lines $L_t=\{y=t(x-1)\}$ through $(1,0)$ and look at the other point of intersection of that line $L_t$ with the curve.
You obtain the point $P_t=(t^2,t(t^2-1))$ and the immersion (=parametrization) is the map associating to the slope $t$ of the line $L_t$ the point $P_t$.

Comment: Thanks Georges. I see that $(t^3-t)^2=t^2(t^2-1)^2$. How did you come up with this immersion, or was it just inspection?

Comment: Algebraic geometers will notice  that the result is purely algebraic and is valid over any field, even one where square roots do not always exist, like $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Dear Buble, no it was not inspection but a standard technique in algebraic geometry to prove that a curve is rational by making use of its singularity. I'll try to sum up the idea in an Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ denote the curve in question, i.e. $c=\{y^2=x(x-1)^2\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. It is easy to verify that $c\setminus\{(1,0)\}$ is a smooth curve (around every point there is a neighborhood with a smooth parametrization). Furthermore, each one of the two "branches" at $(1,0)$ has a smooth parametrization. For example:

$$t\mapsto (t,\sqrt{t}(t-1))$$ and $$t\mapsto(t,-\sqrt{t}(t-1)).$$ Hence the answer is yes.

Comment: So is a manifold immersed if each point is in the image of a smooth parametrization? I only knew of the other implication.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure about the general case, but I think that the 1-dimensional situation is relatively simple. You can glue a few parametrizations to one another and obtain an immersion from the line to the plane.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Btw, what is the parametrization at $(0,0)$, wouldn't the derivative be undefined there?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Since the derivative of $x(x-1)^2$ is not $0$ at $x=0$, near $(0,0)$ $x$ is a smooth function of $y$. (implicit function theorem)

Comment: If I can ask a qualitative question: Let's say you take that "loop" out of the graph and replace it with a straight line running from (0,0) to (1,0).  Do you still have an immersed submanifold?  Do you have a submanifold at all?

Comment: No, neither... This time the singular point is "more singular".