# Determining whether $y^2=x(x-1)^2$ is an immersed submanifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

To start off, I should clarify that the definition of immersed submanifold that I am using is the more restrictive one given by Lee. This says that $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold of M if it is endowed with a topology (not necessarily the subspace topology) with respect to which it is a topological manifold (without boundary), and a smooth structure with respect to which the inclusion map $\iota: S \hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth immersion.

So I am trying to determine whether $M_0 = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\mid y^2=x(x-1)^2\}$ is an immersed submanifold. Here is what it looks like.
[image]
If we were to use the more relaxed definition of an immersed submanifold, i.e. the one that doesn't require injectivity, then we can can parametrize the curve as described in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895559/is-y2-xx-12-an-immersed-submanifold) question. But this parametrization is not injective because $-1 \mapsto (1,0)$ and $1 \mapsto (1,0)$.

My thinking is that in order for this set to be an immersed submanifold, we must show that we can parametrize the set with some smooth map $F:\Bbb{R}\to M_0$ that is injective and an immersion, and if this is not possible, then $M_0$ cannot be an immersed submanifold. *Is this thinking correct?*

Edit: As per AlexL's suggestion, it seems that I don't have to think of of just "parametrizations" from $\Bbb{R}$ to $M_0$. I could have a map from a disconnected manifold to the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the manifold $M=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1 \}$. Then one has a smooth immersion $j : M \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $ t \to (t^2,t^3-t)$ that gives $M_0$.

Comment: Oh wow. That's so simple. I didn't even think to use a disconnected manifold!